# C# ask user for servername and save for everytime application is ran

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, save

I've tried searching but had no luck as I'm not sure I'm using the correct terminology.

I'm trying to figure out how to ask a user to input their server name on the first application run, store that and insert it into filepath/connection string.

Pseudocode for initial run:

1. I see this is the first time you ran this application.  Please input your fileserver name.
2. user inputs: fileserver123x
3. Write Fileserver123x to text file.

Initialize database connection

4. string fileServername = read text file;

connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\'"+fileServerName+@"'\share\folder\Database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");

5. rest of code

I'm looking to see if there is a better/more professional way to store the user file server information other than via text file and read it each time the DB connection is initialized.

Any thoughts?

Comment: That line of code will not compile.

Comment: will it help? http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2010/

Comment: edited post to make it a little more clear to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your concept looks fine, I'd suggest a few improvements:

- Store the file server name in the Windows registry instead of a text file. This is where well-behaved Windows programs store their configuration data.
- Store the complete path to the database instead of the file server name. That way, your customers don't have to use a fixed share/folder name.
- Make a configuration window where this configuration data can be modified. This can also serve as the window you show on your first run.
- Don't read the configuration data *each time* a connection is opened. Read it *once* when your application starts and store it in a global variable.

  <sub>(Note: In general, global variables are a code smell, but storing global configuration data is usually considered a legitimate use case. If you want a more advanced solution that simplifies unit testing, look into dependency injection for your configuration data.)</sub>